# Using watch command for Laravel Mix seems to add a cooldown before it starts to listen for changes again

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using [npm run watch](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#running-mix) watching assets for changes, and it works good except that it takes 10 seconds before it starts to listening for changes again after every compile.

So if I save a file it will successfully compile, but if I make changes and save again before 10 seconds passed nothing happens.

I expect the `npm run watch` to be ready directly after every compilation.

**How can I debug this?** I don't know if this is an issue with Laravel Mix or something else?

I'm using webpack and my VM has a Ubuntu system. My 
This is from **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/main.js', 'public/js/app.js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss: [ tailwindcss('./tailwind-config.js') ],
});
```

Comment: Are you running `npm run watch` within the VM, or on the host?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm running that command in the VM

Comment: For my setup, I found `npm run watch-poll` was more reliable. I found the regular `npm run watch` would sometimes not pickup on the changes, although I don't know if it was a cooldown type thing as you're describing.